# I am unable to find any solution to pass value of API response to new file and use that object values

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I have 2 files:

1. Test Specs
2. API layer (in which all API's are written like cy.request(). I am returning API response from here

I need to use the response of API in my test spec. But when I try to use the response I am getting undefined

That is how I returning my response

```
testFun() {
    cy.request({
      method: "GET",
      url: `${this.objectFactory.url}/api-v7/listings/`,
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: this.objectFactory.authorization,
        cookie: this.objectFactory.cookie,
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      
          return response;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

And in spec file, I am calling this function and getting undefined

Comment: Please add the code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding a return before the cy.request command?

```js
    testFun() {
        return cy.request({
          method: "GET",
          url: `${this.objectFactory.url}/api-v7/listings/`,
          headers: {
            accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: this.objectFactory.authorization,
            cookie: this.objectFactory.cookie,
          },
        });
      }


      # then do
      testFun().then((response) => { do something with response });
```

Comment: Thank-you so much for real quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Return the request from the function, you don't need the `.then()` added.

```js
testFun() {
    return cy.request({
      method: "GET",
      url: `${this.objectFactory.url}/api-v7/listings/`,
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: this.objectFactory.authorization,
        cookie: this.objectFactory.cookie,
      },
    })
  }
```

Use it in the test with a `.then()`

```js
testFun().then(response => {
  // assert response here
})
```

Comment: Thank-you so much for real quick help.